# Some error → HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: wordpress, require

```
require_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/widgets/MCAPI.class.php');
```

I am getting the above error. Actually previously it was pulling the file from here:

```
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'MCAPI.class.php');
```

But I have transferred the file into my theme folder of WordPress here:
inc/widgets/MCAPI.class.php

and used this path:

```
require_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/widgets/MCAPI.class.php');
```

But is throwing error:

**Warning**:  require_once(http://......../wp-content/themes/puck/inc/widgets/MCAPI.class.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in **/home2/kisskiss/public_html/....../wp-content/themes/puck/functions.php** on line **238**

**Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://...../wp-content/themes/puck/inc/widgets/MCAPI.class.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in **/home2/kisskiss/public_html/....../wp-content/themes/puck/functions.php** on line **238**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` which returns an URL while you need a path. You should use `get_template_directory()` so your `require_once` should look like this:

```
require_once(get_template_directory().'/inc/widgets/MCAPI.class.php');
```